Electrons in fractional quantum hall effect
Can we infer from plasma analogy in fractional quantum hall effect that the electrons fractional quantum hall state are all fractionalized? I have heard before the electrons in the state will be fractionalized, but not sure from which argument can we show this?

What do you mean by fractionalized? Do you mean a Laughlin quasiparticle? A composite fermions?

Thanks for clarification. I want to mean Laughlin quasiparticle. My confusion is that the quasi hole and quasi particle are introduced(by lecture note david tong), but I don't know if all the particles in the hall bar would be fractionalzed laughlin quasiparticle?

No they would not. If you excite a Laughlin ground state to a regular Laughlin quasiparticle then you have "one" fractionally charged particle.
